# Wrong date when converting datetime value to date field

Tags: lightning, rest-api, datetime, date, convert

I am using the REST API for creating a new Task record, including an Activity Date in the format `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ`. My current timezone is `UTC+1`.

When submitting a date in the first hour of the day, i.e. for example from `2018-11-19T00:00:00+01:00` to `2018-11-19T00:59:59+01:00`, the Activity date is rendered as the previous day on the Task's detail page in my lightning expirience, here `11/18/2018` (Locale: English (United States)). Only when pushing a later date like `2018-11-19T01:00:00+01:00`, the Activity Date is correct and shows `11/19/2018`.

I then created a custom Date/Time field for the Task and pushed the same dates as above. In that case, every date is rendered correctly, i.e. when pushing `2018-11-19T00:00:00+01:00`, it is rendered correctly as `11/19/2018 12:00 AM`.

In conclusion, it seems that the Activity Date, which has the field type "Date", is ignoring the timezone, while my custom field, which has the field type "Date/Time", is considering the timezone properly. 
This behavior applies not only for Tasks, but for every object that has fields of type Date or Date/Time.

Is there something that I missed or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/159543/58595:

> **DateTime** fields store the time information in UTC and display the appropriate date and time to the user based on the user's personal timezone settings.
>
> **Date** fields contain no time information and completely ignore timezones. Whatever date you specify when you set it will be the date every user sees, with any time and zone information being ignored.