# Reporting Total calls by hour per day

Tags: reporting

I am trying to figure out how to report total calls by hour per day but am having a hard time trying to figure out how I would go about doing this.

e.g. 8AM - 9AM - 30 calls.
     9AM - 10AM - 10 Calls.

and so forth.

with the total calls totaled at the bottom of the report.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been asked before.  If you navigate to this post ([Case Report grouped by Hour of Day](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17241/case-report-grouped-by-hour-of-day)) you will have the full answer you're looking for.  This answer was given by Chris Duncombe